# How can I forward iOS 2FA SMS code to slack?

Tags: ios, swift, two-factor-authentication

With Apple getting ever more stringent by enforcing 2FA on all iOS accounts, a unique challenge that we've encountered is how to setup a system where Apple’s 2FA codes for a shared dev account can be forwarded to perhaps our private slack channel?  Hence enabling multiple members on a team access to Apple’s services.

Comment: Each team member should have their own Apple ID linked to your team. That is the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I got so annoyed by this that we then developed a hack.*

It’s a Python script that’s running in a terminal on the mac mini CI machine and using some vision SDK tooling, checks the screen every few seconds for the 2FA dialog pop-up.

[image]

If it finds it, it then navigates the pop-up, crops the 2FA code, does OCR on it, and relays the code through the Slack API to a dedicated internal *buildbot* channel that our devs get notified on.

Sample cropped 2FA code screenshot:

[image]

The result, is the general shared apple id account is now much more convenient and efficient to access by our devs for CI/CD or any other client App Store info updates.

So that’s one way to do it.